# How do I create a 3D array in matlab?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Matlab: How to create a 3D matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794191/matlab-how-to-create-a-3d-matrix)

I have 2 vectors as follows:

```
A= 5 x 10 ( 5 rows, 10 column)
B= 5 x 6  ( 5 rows , 6 column)
```

How do I create a 3D array, meaning `5 x 10 x 6`, but not filled with zeros?

Comment: in fact the column of the matrix B must be the values of the 3rd dimension

Comment: You cannot create a 3D matrix from your vectors the way you want it. Your vectors have only `50+30=80` elements, whereas the 3D matrix you described has `300` elements.

Comment: emmm, let me describe,,, the row in both array A and B is representing image name 1 to 5, so meaning in row 1 of array A, 10 values representing related to image 1, and row 1 of array B have another 6 value representing the same image, so how can I put all this in 3D array?

Comment: I need to construct a tensor for that, but I dont know how to do

Comment: If your tensor is of size (5,10,6), what number do you want to put in position (i,j,k) ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a 3D matrix is what you want here. I would suggest the following options:

Option 1. Cell array

```
>> A = rand(5,10); B = rand(5,6); 
>> {A, B}

ans = 

    [5x10 double]    [5x6 double]
```

Option 2. Cell matrix

```
>> clear C; for i=1:5, C{i,1} = A(i,:)'; C{i,2} = B(i,:)'; end; C

C = 

    [10x1 double]    [6x1 double]
    [10x1 double]    [6x1 double]
    [10x1 double]    [6x1 double]
    [10x1 double]    [6x1 double]
    [10x1 double]    [6x1 double]
```

Option 3. Concatenate the arrays, and then simply index against the parts you need.

```
>> C = [A,B]; size(C)

ans =

    5    16
```

Option 4. Use a structure array

```
>> clear C; for i=1:5, C(i).A = A(i,:)'; C(i).B = B(i,:)'; end; C

C = 

1x5 struct array with fields:
    A
    B
```

If you think of a 3D matrix as a cube, and a 2D matrix as a square, you should see that what you are trying to do is create a cube from two squares, leaving the volume of the cube empty (as well as the other four sides).